# Docker compose: How to invoke command in one container from another?

Tags: networking, command, docker-compose, entry-point

I understand docker compose creates a network of containers.

Now, is there a way to provide a program implemented in a `container_B` and invoke it from *within*  `container A`?

Consider this example:

```
version: "3.2"

services:
  container_A:
    image: 'alpine:latest'
    links:
      - container_B

  container_B:
    image: 'python:3.7.0a3-alpine3.7'
```

I would then like to use `python` from *within* `container_A` - be it interactively or from scripts I write.

Of course, this is just an over-simplified example, but I'd like to provide a container for any program, in this example `python`, but could be `FFmpeg`, or `vim` or you name it.

So the question is, whether there is a way to use containers not only over the network, but also invoke programs contained within them?

Help will be *much* appreciated.